# Can I mod Minecraft on a Raspberry Pi 3B

Tags: pi-3

Does the pi even have enough RAM? when I tried to run `./gradlew setupDecompWorkspace` it returns `non-zero exit value 1`. Here is the gradle log.

```
#################################################
         ForgeGradle 2.2-SNAPSHOT-d13a6c8        
  https://github.com/MinecraftForge/ForgeGradle  
#################################################
           Powered by MCP unknown               
         http://modcoderpack.com             
     by: Searge, ProfMobius, Fesh0r,         
     R4wk, ZeuX, IngisKahn, bspkrs           
#################################################
:deobfCompileDummyTask
:deobfProvidedDummyTask
:getVersionJson
:extractUserdev UP-TO-DATE
:extractDependencyATs SKIPPED
:extractMcpData SKIPPED
:extractMcpMappings SKIPPED
:genSrgs SKIPPED
:downloadClient SKIPPED
:downloadServer SKIPPED
:splitServerJar SKIPPED
:mergeJars SKIPPED
:deobfMcSRG SKIPPED
:decompileMc
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 3145728KB object heap
:decompileMc FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':decompileMc'.
> Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm32-vfp-hflt/bin/java'' 
finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1 mins 3.488 secs
```

Comment: It sure hasn't 3145728KB, that's 3GB, RAM. You have to add swapspace or build it on a machine with more RAM.

Answer (score 1):

Notice the line `Could not reserve enough space for 3145728KB object heap`. That's equivalent to 3 GB, which is more than the [1 GB of RAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi#RAM) available to the Pi 3.

You will need to tell Gradle to use a smaller heap; somewhere between 512 MB and 768 MB is probably wise, but you'll need to test it and see. To set the heap size, create a directory called `.gradle` in your home directory, and in there, a file called `gradle.properties`. If you're using the default `pi` user, the commands to do that in the terminal are:

```
mkdir ~/.gradle
cd ~/.gradle
touch gradle.properties
```

Then, in that file, you need to add the following line:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx512M
```

(you can do that in the terminal by running `nano gradle.properties`, typing the line above, then pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> then <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit).

Then, rerun the Gradle build (you will need to change directory back to where you were before with `cd`) and test to see if that works. If it doesn't, try tweaking the `512M` to other values, and if none work, you are likely out of luck.

Comment: It is still attempting to use the 3GB heap size even with these tweaks